# training and test using same data but test accuracy very low

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to machine learning, I have built a mobilenet model to classify gray image. the training accuracy was good(above 90%) but the test accuracy was very low(20%~30%).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiQ5k.png)
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiQ5k.png)
first I thought it's overfitting, I tried data augmentation, simplify model(take away most of it's convolution layer)

```
# A generic MobileNet block
def mobile_net_block(x, filters, stride, depth_multiplier, block_id):
prefix = 'block_{}_'.format(block_id)

# Depthwise
x = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size=3, strides=stride, depth_multiplier = depth_multiplier, activation=None, use_bias=True, padding='same', kernel_initializer="he_normal", depthwise_regularizer=regularizers.l2(4e-5), name=prefix + 'depthwise')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name=prefix + 'depthwise_BN')(x)
x = ReLU(6., name=prefix + 'depthwise_ReLU')(x)

# Pointwise
x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=True, activation=None, kernel_initializer="he_normal", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(4e-5), name=prefix + 'project')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name=prefix + 'project_BN')(x)
x = ReLU(6., name=prefix + 'pointwise_ReLU')(x)

return x
#Create Build
def create_model(rows, cols, channels, lr_initial):

# encoder - input
model_input = keras.Input(shape=(rows, cols, channels), name='input_image')
x = model_input

# model architechture
x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer="he_normal", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(4e-5), name='Conv1')(model_input)

x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=64, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=0)
x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=64, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=1)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=256, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=2)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=512, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=3)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=512, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=4)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=512, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=5)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=512, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=6)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=512, stride=1, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=7)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=1024, stride=2, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=8)
# x = mobile_net_block(x, filters=1024, stride=2, depth_multiplier=1, block_id=9)

# Decoder
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='global_average_pool')(x)
x = Dense(3, activation='softmax', use_bias=True, name='Logits')(x)

# create model of MobileNet (for CIFAR-10)
model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x, name='mobilenet_cifar10')

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(０．０１), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
model = create_model(size, size, 1, 0.01)
model.summary()
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30, verbose=1)
history = model.fit(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch=15,
  epochs=25,
  validation_data=validation_generator,
  validation_steps=5,
  verbose=2,
  callbacks = [earlystop])
```

However it still doesn't work. As a result, I'm thinking that what if I use same data for training and testing. The accuracy should have same performance or even better, in fact it doesn't. Could anyone explain that?
sorry I don't know why the indentation are all mess up after pasting code on this website.

Comment: Please consider that It is not good to comment on parts of architecture and expect similar behavior. What is your learning rate? What is your fit function? A better way to test the code and architecture is to use a high learning rate and a simple dataset to see if it train loss drops very fast. you can test with MNIST it is available in Keras. 
Depending on your setup it might take many epochs and a long time to see great accuracy on test set.

Comment: 1. sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean "It is not good to comment on parts of architecture and expect similar behavior."?

Comment: you have commented out many filters of architecture. it totally changes the behavior of the model. Please share more details.